# the direction of two components , how can Financial Report Generator get data from database?

Tags: architecture, coding-style

I'am reading the book clean architecture. i have a question , please help me answer:

In this image, the Interactor component is referenced to Database component

- Database --> Interactor
- Financial Report Generator uses the interface Financial Data Gateway and Financial Entities
- Financial Report Generator doesn't see any instance Financial Data Gateway.

How can Financial Report Generator class can get data without any instance Financial Data Mapper ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The diagram shows that the Financial Data Mapper class implements the Financial Data Gateway interface. Since the Financial Report Generator has a reference to some Financial Data Gateway, we can assume that the implementation (instance) object is a Financial Data Mapper in this architecure, since that's the only class that implements the interface. This gives it access to the Financial Database.

If you needed to create a financial report based on some other data source than the database, you'd introduce a new source with its own implementation of a Financial Data Gateway.